# Search by a property of a reference

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have the following models:

```
class Station(db.Model):
    code = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class Schedule(db.Model):
    tripCode = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    station = db.ReferenceProperty(Station, required=True)    
    arrivalTime = db.TimeProperty(required=True)
    departureTime = db.TimeProperty(required=True)
```

How can I order **programatically** all the Schedules by Station's name?

Something like Schedule.all().order('station.name')

Answer (score 0):

You will to de-normalize your models or sort the results in memory:

```
Schedule.all().fetch(100).sort(key=lambda s: s.station.name)
```

(code not tested)

Comment: all() is a Query, not a list.  It can't be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

After use sort i think you need to fetch all entities:

```
Schedule.all().fetch (100).sort(key=lambda s: s.station.name)
```

May be you can also [use collection name](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty).
But i think the jbochi answer is better :)

```
[x.schedule_set.get () for x in Station.all ().order ('name')]
```

Comment: @jbochi: Unfortunately as wooble says, fetch returns a Query so isn't sortable. @Sahid: this list only returns the first shedule and station of every station, to return all the schedules it can be something like [y.fetch(1000) for y in [x.schedule_set.get () for x in Station.all ().order ('name')] that returns a list of list